# Edit Multiple Places in iPhoto '11?

Tags: photos.app

I've recently upgraded from iPhoto '08 to '11 and am in the process of cleaning up my geotagging.  Most of my photos had been geotagged outside of iPhoto, but for a lot of them it wasn't as accurate as I'd like.  So what I've done is flag all of the photos where I'd like to zero in a little more on the map.  Working one at a time I can just select the photo and, in the info pane, drag the existing pin a little bit to a new location on the map.  Works fine.

However, I have large swaths of photos which are all very nearly in the exact same spot (taken in the same room in a building, for example).  When I highlight multiple photos, though, the map in the info pane doesn't let me drag the pin.  (I'm guessing that the pin shown is for only a single photo, such as the first one selected.)  Is there a way I can re-assign the place on the map for multiple photos?

**Edit:** Requested screen cap:
[image]

Comment: That's so weird considering it used to let you do it.  I'm trying to set the location of a batch and I don't want to do it one by one.

They've even got the batch change option, "place" should have been there before.  And it should be there now.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found a way. Remove any places that are already assigned to individual photos in the album/event. Then select all the photos and set a location. It should now assign that location to all the photos.